# iOS simulator crashes at startup (intermittently), no crashes on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, sigabrt

My app crashes on the iPhone 6.1 Simulator. It crashes on startup, but not every time. In fact, I can't get it to crash two times in a row. Sometimes it's every other time I hit run, sometimes it's every three times I hit run. The crash is a SIGABRT and produces no error messages. I set a breakpoint on all exceptions, but it always breaks at UIApplicationMain(...) in main.m

The backtrace produces:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x91398a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x91398a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
frame #1: 0x95c31b2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
frame #2: 0x023e857b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x02d92b4e GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348
frame #4: 0x02d9269f GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123
frame #5: 0x02d92c1f GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36
frame #6: 0x00ee0d99 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
frame #7: 0x0000277d MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff388) + 141 at main.m:16
```

The app doesn't seem to crash on the device, but this is very annoying and just started recently. I've tried resetting content, restarting Xcode, restarting my computer -- no luck. Any ideas how I could debug this?

Comment: Let me guess, you've upgraded to 10.8.4? There is a problem with the simulator after the upgrade.

Comment: Ah, yes that's when this started. I just updated to 10.8.4 this morning.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue too. Is there a way to submit a support request for this type of thing or find out when Apple expects to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, this happened to me with the beta 10.8.4 as well. Only solution is to stop the app, wait a couple seconds, then rebuild on the simulator. Just pressing build/run once a build is currently running is what causes this.

*** Update ***
As of Xcode Version 4.6.3 this issue has been addressed. If anyone is still having issues please post it here.

Comment: I've got the latest version of Mavericks (10.9.1), xCode (just downloaded now), and the iOS simulator (4.3).  Upon launch the simulator spins for awhile then crashes with a dialog allowing me to quit, relaunch or switch SDKs.  I'm a total newb re: xCode / iOS (just trying to learn it out of a book, the first step of which is, "make sure you can run the iOS simulator") but this obviously seems an issue.  Any help appreciated.  thx

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the scheme and switching the debugger from LLDB to GDB (or vice versa) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem and found changing the Deployment Target from 6.0 to 5.0 fixed it for me. Obviously only if your App will work on 5.0 will this work.